# Posting Base64 encoded values in phpmyadmin from Android

Tags: php, android

In my app i am trying to post image from android to phpmyadmin i have also created php code which is here:

**MyPhp.php**:

```
<?php
$servername = "dontneedthis";
$username = "also";
$password = "dont care";
$dbname = "bla bla";


$conn =mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password);

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}


    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    $binary=base64_decode($base);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (image) VALUES('{$binary}')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

When i upload image from android i get an error where it is shown that he doent understand this :

```
INSERT INTO table (image) VALUES
```

And he shows a lot of symbols which i do not recognise. I have created table where is a row where you can add 100 000 symbols of `TEXT` I tried to add the value as `blob` and tried to change collation to `binary` nothing worked do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't anyone ever bother to properly quote their stuff?

`table` is a keyword in all SQL dialects I know, and hence causes a syntax error.
But for that reason, quotes and backticks have been invented.

Do this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`image`) VALUES ...
```

and you should have one problem less.

Also, you have to escape your `$binary` variable, otherwise it's gonna break your `'` quotes:

```
$binary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, base64_decode($base));
```

Comment: Is still the exact same passage the problem?

Comment: No now it just show how i changed it like you said, it shows error INSERT INTO `table` (`image`)

Comment: Try `$binary = mysqli_real_escape_string(base64_decode($base));`

Comment: Well it show an error mysqli_real_escape_string expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ...(file location)

Comment: Right, sorry. That would be `$binary = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, base64_decode($base));`